# Bootstrap modal is blocked

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I have written a code to show popup using a bootstrap modal.

It worked, but all element is blocked. I don't know what wrong with my code.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div id="add_data_Modal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add data</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="post" name="insert_form" id="insert_form">
                    <label>Số thuê bao</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" />
                    <br />
                    <label>Speed number</label>
                    <input type="text" name="spd_number" id="spd_number" class="form-control" />
                    <br />
                    <label>Dial number</label>
                    <input type="text" name="dial_number" id="dial_number" class="form-control"/>   
                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="ADD" class="btn btn-success"/>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Im guessing the CSS for the id="add_data_Modal" is above your modal which is why you cant access it but I am not sure because you didnt provide any of your CSS code.

Comment: Use correctly with the documentation it will work. You must have added some extra css if this is right

Comment: I've created a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/d8v4w6zo/ and it's working fine, try to look at your js console maybe there is some errors

Comment: and post js and css code used

Comment: Agree with @Ashishsah. If you're going to use something like Bootstrap, don't start randomly throwing in your own CSS unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: try inspecting in your browse what actually is blocking your modal

Comment: Let me check, thanks for yours help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your code, I think the cause may be due to your code redundant or missing a close tag. Usually missing or excess `div` tags.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve your issue,following this link.

[bootstrap modal examples](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#how-it-works)

As if have different css files,check that css files also.because some times you added classes or ID can be override.

Comment: For me it was because the containing element where the dialog is located has a z-index set. Not to a higher value but the stacking context made it stack to the back. Very helpful link.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap document indicate: Whenever possible, place your modal HTML in a top-level position to avoid potential interference from other elements.You’ll likely run into issues when nesting a .modal within another fixed element.

If you realy can't find error, don't know whether parent container of id="add_data_Modal" against the Bootstrap's rules. Try below code:

```
$('#add_data_Modal').appendTo('body');
```

Using jquery to place your modal HTML to body. In case you can sure your modal HTML in a top-level position.

**Update**--------

If someone using Angular this works - sort of. But... this has a nasty side effect as well: Because Angular re-renders the view every time it's accessed, a new #add_data_Modal element is created each and everytime.

This behavior causes duplication of the the elements and on occasion causes the wrong data to come up.

Fix this by clearing out the modal before append to body like below:

```
$('#"body>#add_data_Modal').remove();
$('#add_data_Modal').appendTo('body');
```